# Appending Python Dictionary for unordered data

Tags: python

I have a large JSON file I am trying to extract specific data from, then consolidate a subset into a dictionary.  Within the JSON file, multiple objects reference the same name (person), but each object contains separate information about that person (e.g. One object has their phone numbers, another has their address, another has their email).  So far, extracting the data has not been an issue.  Where I am struggling is building the dictionary to consolidate everything.

What I am trying to do is:

1) Create the dictionary:

```
names = {}
```

2) Since the data is unordered, I need to create a key for that person.

```
n = name
names['name'] = n
```

3) As I identify the record type, then add that persons data to the dictionary

```
p = phoneNumber
a = Address
names[n]['phoneNumber'] = p
names[n]['Address'] = a
```

In the end, once the entire JSON file is iterated over, the dictionary should be complete.

I suspect my code works when creating a new Person that didn't exist prior, but when I add additional information, I am overwriting the prior keys vs. appending the dictionary entry.

What I am wondering is:

1) If my overwrite vs. append logic correct?

2) How can I accomplish this?  Is using a dictionary bad for this?

Comment: "I am overwriting the prior keys vs. appending the dictionary entry." yes, of course. `dict` objects have unique keys, you cannot "append" to dicts, you assign a value to a key. If you assign to the same key, it overwrites. Not sure exactly what you are trying to accopmlish, what would be an example input/output?

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: sounds like you need `defaultdict` and initialize it with `d = defaultdict(dict)` where each key is the name and the value is the dictionary with neceesary attributes as the key and the value being the actual value

Comment: What is `names['name']=n` supposed to accomplish?  Given what follows, it ought to be data about a person whose name is "name".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga correct, I want to append the dict, and if a key already exists, append the addition off that key.  What lio posted looks correct, but my data is not ordered.  As I iterate over my JSON file, I want to add data, piece by piece, using their name as the key.  In the end, the dict should look like what lio posted below.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, youre json look like that:

```
names = {
    'Jack Benson': {
        'phone number': '+4435025015',
        'adress': '21 jump street'},
    'Antoine Vincent': {
        'phone number': '+4421545486',
        'adress': '742 Evergreen Terrace '}
        }
```

To create something like that, the simplest way can be :

```
names = {}
names['Jack Benson'] = {}
names['Jack Benson']['phone number'] = '+4435025015'
names['Jack Benson']['adress'] =  '21 jump street'

names['Antoine Vincent'] = {}
names['Antoine Vincent']['phone number'] = '+4421545486'
names['Antoine Vincent']['adress'] =  '742 Evergreen Terrace'
```

> 1) If my overwrite vs. append logic correct?

```
n = name
names['name'] = n
```

if name is an empty dict, yes, everything is correcty

> 2) How can I accomplish this? Is using a dictionary bad for this?
>   That's always a good idea to use python built-in's for simple data structures. It's readable and easy to serialize for json.

good luck.

Lio

Comment: Thanks, this helps.  Since my data is unordered, how do I check is a Person key already exists to avoid doing "names['Jack Benson'] = {}" and removing prior additions?  Is there a "=+" option I can do (create is non-exist, append if already exists?)

Comment: @EthanB , AFAIK there isn't a "+=" option for dicts, but you can easily check if a key exists using "if key in dict". (By the way, this was answered on another question. Next time, try to search first.)